# how to configure a email functionality in play-java 2.5.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I wrote the following code for email functionality:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
public class MailController extends Controller {
public Result sendEmail() throws EmailException {
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    String authuser = ".......@gmail.com";
    String authpwd = "XXXXXXX";
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setFrom(".........@gmail.com", "SenderName");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setHtmlMsg("<html><body><h1>welcome to u</h1></body></html>");
    //email.addTo(".......@gmail.com", "receiver name");
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.send();
     return play.mvc.Results.ok("Success");
  }
}
```

However, I'm facing problems (such as exceptions getting caught in Netty).

I added a plugin in bulid.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1"
)
```

application.conf:

```
# Mailer
# ~~~~~
play.mailer {
  host=smtpout.secureserver.net
  port=587
  ssl=false
  tls=false
  user=my username
  password=my password
  debug=false
  mock=false

}
```

This is one of the errors that I'm facing:

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler$
        at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:45)
        at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:65)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:47)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:82)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:129)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
```

How can I fix this?

my application.config file is as below

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ConfigFile
# ~~~~~
# Play uses HOCON as its configuration file format.  HOCON has a number
# of advantages over other config formats, but there are two things that
# can be used when modifying settings.
#
# You can include other configuration files in this main application.conf file:
#include "extra-config.conf"
#
# You can declare variables and substitute for them:
#mykey = ${some.value}
#
# And if an environment variable exists when there is no other subsitution, then
# HOCON will fall back to substituting environment variable:
#mykey = ${JAVA_HOME}

## Akka
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaAkka#Configuration
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaAkka#Configuration
# ~~~~~
# Play uses Akka internally and exposes Akka Streams and actors in Websockets and
# other streaming HTTP responses.
akka {
  # "akka.log-config-on-start" is extraordinarly useful because it log the complete
  # configuration at INFO level, including defaults and overrides, so it s worth
  # putting at the very top.
  #
  # Put the following in your conf/logback.xml file:
  #
  # <logger name="akka.actor" level="INFO" />
  #
  # And then uncomment this line to debug the configuration.
  #
  #log-config-on-start = true
}

## Secret key
# http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to sign Play's session cookie.
# This must be changed for production, but we don't recommend you change it in this file.
play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

## Modules
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Modules
# ~~~~~
# Control which modules are loaded when Play starts.  Note that modules are
# the replacement for "GlobalSettings", which are deprecated in 2.5.x.
# Please see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/GlobalSettings
# for more information.
#
# You can also extend Play functionality by using one of the publically available
# Play modules: https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ModuleDirectory
play.modules {
  # By default, Play will load any class called Module that is defined
  # in the root package (the "app" directory), or you can define them
  # explicitly below.
  # If there are any built-in modules that you want to disable, you can list them here.
  #enabled += my.application.Module

  # If there are any built-in modules that you want to disable, you can list them here.
  #disabled += ""
}

## IDE
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/IDE
# ~~~~~
# Depending on your IDE, you can add a hyperlink for errors that will jump you
# directly to the code location in the IDE in dev mode. The following line makes 
# use of the IntelliJ IDEA REST interface: 
#play.editor=http://localhost:63342/api/file/?file=%s&line=%s 

## Internationalisation
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaI18N
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaI18N
# ~~~~~
# Play comes with its own i18n settings, which allow the user's preferred language
# to map through to internal messages, or allow the language to be stored in a cookie.
play.i18n {
  # The application languages
  langs = [ "en" ]

  # Whether the language cookie should be secure or not
  #langCookieSecure = true

  # Whether the HTTP only attribute of the cookie should be set to true
  #langCookieHttpOnly = true
}

## Play HTTP settings
# ~~~~~
play.http {
  ## Router
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaRouting
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaRouting
  # ~~~~~
  # Define the Router object to use for this application.
  # This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
  # so make sure this is the entry point.
  # Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
  # So for an application router like `my.application.Router`,
  # you may need to define a router file `conf/my.application.routes`.
  # Default to Routes in the root package (aka "apps" folder) (and conf/routes)
  #router = my.application.Router

  ## Action Creator
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaActionCreator
  # ~~~~~
  #actionCreator = null

  ## ErrorHandler
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaRouting
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaRouting
  # ~~~~~
  # If null, will attempt to load a class called ErrorHandler in the root package,
  #errorHandler = null

  ## Filters
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaHttpFilters
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaHttpFilters
  # ~~~~~
  # Filters run code on every request. They can be used to perform
  # common logic for all your actions, e.g. adding common headers.
  # Defaults to "Filters" in the root package (aka "apps" folder)
  # Alternatively you can explicitly register a class here.
  #filters = my.application.Filters

  ## Session & Flash
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaSessionFlash
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaSessionFlash
  # ~~~~~
  session {
    # Sets the cookie to be sent only over HTTPS.
    #secure = true

    # Sets the cookie to be accessed only by the server.
    #httpOnly = true

    # Sets the max-age field of the cookie to 5 minutes.
    # NOTE: this only sets when the browser will discard the cookie. Play will consider any
    # cookie value with a valid signature to be a valid session forever. To implement a server side session timeout,
    # you need to put a timestamp in the session and check it at regular intervals to possibly expire it.
    #maxAge = 300

    # Sets the domain on the session cookie.
    #domain = "example.com"
  }

  flash {
    # Sets the cookie to be sent only over HTTPS.
    #secure = true

    # Sets the cookie to be accessed only by the server.
    #httpOnly = true
  }
}

## Netty Provider
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsNetty
# ~~~~~
play.server.netty {
  # Whether the Netty wire should be logged
  #log.wire = true

  # If you run Play on Linux, you can use Netty's native socket transport
  # for higher performance with less garbage.
  #transport = "native"
}

## WS (HTTP Client)
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaWS#Configuring-WS
# ~~~~~
# The HTTP client primarily used for REST APIs.  The default client can be
# configured directly, but you can also create different client instances
# with customized settings. You must enable this by adding to build.sbt:
#
# libraryDependencies += ws // or javaWs if using java
#
play.ws {
  # Sets HTTP requests not to follow 302 requests
  #followRedirects = false

  # Sets the maximum number of open HTTP connections for the client.
  #ahc.maxConnectionsTotal = 50

  ## WS SSL
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/WsSSL
  # ~~~~~
  ssl {
    # Configuring HTTPS with Play WS does not require programming.  You can
    # set up both trustManager and keyManager for mutual authentication, and
    # turn on JSSE debugging in development with a reload.
    #debug.handshake = true
    #trustManager = {
    #  stores = [
    #    { type = "JKS", path = "exampletrust.jks" }
    #  ]
    #}
  }
}

## Cache
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaCache
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaCache
# ~~~~~
# Play comes with an integrated cache API that can reduce the operational
# overhead of repeated requests. You must enable this by adding to build.sbt:
#
# libraryDependencies += cache
#
play.cache {
  # If you want to bind several caches, you can bind the individually
  #bindCaches = ["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache"]
}

## Filters
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters
# ~~~~~
# There are a number of built-in filters that can be enabled and configured
# to give Play greater security.  You must enable this by adding to build.sbt:
#
# libraryDependencies += filters
#
play.filters {
  ## CORS filter configuration
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/CorsFilter
  # ~~~~~
  # CORS is a protocol that allows web applications to make requests from the browser
  # across different domains.
  # NOTE: You MUST apply the CORS configuration before the CSRF filter, as CSRF has
  # dependencies on CORS settings.
  cors {
    # Filter paths by a whitelist of path prefixes
    #pathPrefixes = ["/some/path", ...]

    # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
    #allowedOrigins = ["http://www.example.com"]

    # The allowed HTTP methods. If null, all methods are allowed
    #allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  }

  ## CSRF Filter
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaCsrf#Applying-a-global-CSRF-filter
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaCsrf#Applying-a-global-CSRF-filter
  # ~~~~~
  # Play supports multiple methods for verifying that a request is not a CSRF request.
  # The primary mechanism is a CSRF token. This token gets placed either in the query string
  # or body of every form submitted, and also gets placed in the users session.
  # Play then verifies that both tokens are present and match.
  csrf {
    # Sets the cookie to be sent only over HTTPS
    #cookie.secure = true

    # Defaults to CSRFErrorHandler in the root package.
    #errorHandler = MyCSRFErrorHandler
  }

  ## Security headers filter configuration
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SecurityHeaders
  # ~~~~~
  # Defines security headers that prevent XSS attacks.
  # If enabled, then all options are set to the below configuration by default:
  headers {
    # The X-Frame-Options header. If null, the header is not set.
    #frameOptions = "DENY"

    # The X-XSS-Protection header. If null, the header is not set.
    #xssProtection = "1; mode=block"

    # The X-Content-Type-Options header. If null, the header is not set.
    #contentTypeOptions = "nosniff"

    # The X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies header. If null, the header is not set.
    #permittedCrossDomainPolicies = "master-only"

    # The Content-Security-Policy header. If null, the header is not set.
    #contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self'"
  }

  ## Allowed hosts filter configuration
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/AllowedHostsFilter
  # ~~~~~
  # Play provides a filter that lets you configure which hosts can access your application.
  # This is useful to prevent cache poisoning attacks.
  hosts {
    # Allow requests to example.com, its subdomains, and localhost:9000.
    #allowed = [".example.com", "localhost:9000"]
  }
}

## Evolutions
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# Evolutions allows database scripts to be automatically run on startup in dev mode
# for database migrations. You must enable this by adding to build.sbt:
#
# libraryDependencies += evolutions
#
play.evolutions {
  # You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
  #db.default.enabled = false
}

## Database Connection Pool
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsJDBC
# ~~~~~
# Play doesn't require a JDBC database to run, but you can easily enable one.
#
# libraryDependencies += jdbc
#
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }
}

## JDBC Datasource
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaDatabase
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaDatabase
# ~~~~~
# Once JDBC datasource is set up, you can work with several different
# database options:
#
# Slick (Scala preferred option): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/PlaySlick
# JPA (Java preferred option): https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaJPA
# EBean: https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaEbean
# Anorm: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaAnorm
#
db {
  # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
  # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Developing-with-the-H2-Database
  #default.driver = org.h2.Driver
  #default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
  #default.username = sa
  #default.password = ""

  # You can turn on SQL logging for any datasource
  # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Highlights25#Logging-SQL-statements
  #default.logSql=true
}

#play.mailer {
#  default.host=smtp.gmail.com
#  default.port=587
#  ssl=false
#  default.tls=true
#  default.user=.......gmail.com
#  default.password=mypassword
#  default.debug=true
#  default.mock=false
#}
```

and this is my build.sbt file

```
name := """play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1"
)
```

Comment: You seem to be using Java. Yet the DefaultHttpErrorHandler seems to be the one for Scala.. (note the package 'play.api.http' (scala) vs 'play.http' (java)

Comment: i did some change and see my code as above. in that i never use play.api.http and play.http but i am facing the same issue. if i write SMTP configuration in java class mails will be sending bur writing in app.conf file we facing issue

Comment: Can you shared your application.conf?

Comment: i added my applicatin.conf file in above

Comment: Hmm.. have you configured the ```PlayJava``` plugin in your build.sbt?

Comment: no i just added mailer plugin only

Comment: see above i added my bulid.sbt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added a plugin for mailer

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1"
)
```

any my java code

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class MailController extends Controller {


  public Result sendEmail() throws EmailException {
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    String authuser = "..........@gmail.com";
    String authpwd = "XXXXXX";
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setFrom("from@gmail.com", "SenderName");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setHtmlMsg("<html><body><h1>welcome to u</h1></body></html>");
    email.addTo("to@gmail.com", "receiver name");
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.send();
 return play.mvc.Results.ok("Success");
  }
}
```

like this every time i have to write SMTP configuration in every class
so i have to config SMTP configuration in appliction.config file only.
if any suggestion share it